# Argo workflows starting step on file change

Tags: cicd, argo-workflows, argo

I need conditional step based on files changes in directory same what e.g. [this](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/step-options/#Condition-changesets) is doing for Bitbucket pipelines. How can i achive it with argo workflows?

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
        kind: Sensor
        metadata:
          name: {{`{{workflow.parameters.cluster}}-{{workflow.parameters.environment}}-{{workflow.parameters.name}}`}}-sensor
        spec:
          template:
            serviceAccountName: admin
          eventBusName: argo-events-bus 
          dependencies:
            - name: gitlab-pr
              eventSourceName: gitlab-es
              eventName: company
              filters:
                dataLogicalOperator: "and"
                data:
                  - path: "body.ref"
                    type: "string"
                    value:
                      - "refs/heads/{{`{{workflow.parameters.branch}}`}}"
                  - path: "body.repository.name"
                    type: "string"
                    value:
                      - "{{`{{workflow.parameters.repository}}`}}"
            - name: gitlab-pr-migration
              eventSourceName: gitlab-es
              eventName: company
              filters:
                data:
                  - path: "[body.commits.#.modified.@flatten,body.commits.#.added.@flatten,body.commits.#.removed.@flatten].@flatten.@flatten"
                    type: string
                    value:
                      - ".database/*"
                      - ".app/Schema/*"
          triggers:
            - template:
                name: icon-trigger
                conditions: "gitlab-pr"
                k8s:
                  operation: create
                  source:
                    resource:
                      apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
                      kind: Workflow
                      metadata:
                        generateName: {{`{{workflow.parameters.cluster}}-{{workflow.parameters.name}}-{{workflow.parameters.environment}}`}}-
                      spec:
                        arguments:
                          parameters:
                          - name: checkout-sha
                          - name: branch
                            value: {{`{{workflow.parameters.branch}}`}}
                          - name: environment
                            value: {{`{{workflow.parameters.environment}}`}}
                          - name: cluster
                            value: {{`{{workflow.parameters.cluster}}`}}
                          - name: migration
                            value: false
                        workflowTemplateRef:
                          name: {{`{{workflow.parameters.name}}`}}-withmigration
                  parameters:
                    - src:
                        dependencyName: gitlab
                        dataKey: body.checkout_sha
                      dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
            - template:
                name: icon-trigger
                conditions: "gitlab-pr && gitlab-pr-migration"
                k8s:
                  operation: create
                  source:
                    resource:
                      apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
                      kind: Workflow
                      metadata:
                        generateName: {{`{{workflow.parameters.cluster}}-{{workflow.parameters.name}}-{{workflow.parameters.environment}}`}}-
                      spec:
                        arguments:
                          parameters:
                          - name: checkout-sha
                          - name: branch
                            value: {{`{{workflow.parameters.branch}}`}}
                          - name: environment
                            value: {{`{{workflow.parameters.environment}}`}}
                          - name: cluster
                            value: {{`{{workflow.parameters.cluster}}`}}
                          - name: migration
                            value: true
                        workflowTemplateRef:
                          name: {{`{{workflow.parameters.name}}`}}-withmigration
                  parameters:
                    - src:
                        dependencyName: gitlab
                        dataKey: body.checkout_sha
                      dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
```

With this config, I'm getting error that I can not reuse same event source as different dependency in same sensor. Do anyone had something simmilar problem or know how to solve it with argo workflows?